# Urban Airship phonegap 3.5 with Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, urbanairship.com

I am trying to use the latest version of Urban Airship Javscript SDK (3.5) with my Phonegap application using Phonegap Build. The official Phonegap build documentation only links to a hosted version of 2.7.0

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1353

I found version 3.5.0 on NPM but I can't seem to get it to install properly using Phonegap Build. Am I doing something wrong? My `config.xml` file looks like:

```
<gap:plugin name="urbanairship-cordova" source="npm" version="3.5.0" />
<!-- Urban Airship app credentials -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.production_app_key" value="Your Production App Key" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.production_app_secret" value="Your Production App Secret" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.development_app_key" value="********" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.development_app_secret" value="********" />

<!-- Required for Android. -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.gcm_sender" value="Your GCM Sender ID" />

<!-- If the app is in production or not -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.in_production" value="false" />

<!-- Optional config values -->

<!-- Enable push when the application launches -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.enable_push_onlaunch" value="true" />

<!-- Override the Android notification icon -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.notification_icon" value="ic_notification" />

<!-- Specify the notification accent color for Android API 21+ (Lollipop) -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.notification_accent_color" value="#0000ff" />

<!-- Clear the iOS badge on launch -->
<preference name="com.urbanairship.clear_badge_onlaunch" value="true" />
```

Comment: The stock answer on [Nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi), the official *Phonegap Build* forum, is to ask the author.

Comment: Android? iOS? whats the error? http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle/

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through following link?

[Documentation of Urbanairship integration](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html)

And do you have install following plugin in your project?

[Urban Airship PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push)

then if you have still facing errors please put error log or trying to looks errors in [Urbanairship console](https://go.urbanairship.com/) also.